# Qt: set QGraphicScene wider than the window? (Or: adding scroll bars to scene)

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to add to a scene a lot of items. To this end, the scene should be much wider than the main window. The problem is that if I set the rect of the scene wider than the width of the main window, I can't reach the part of the scene that located beyond the window.

In other words, my question is how to define the scene as scroll area (or, how to add scroll bars to the scene).

I have seen an example that combine a scroll area with a QGraphicsView with a layout object, but didn't understand it, and didn't success to reproduce it in my code.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b35JF4LqtBs should help you. Really good tutorial series. I've familiarized myself with Qt through them.

Comment: Thanks @LogicStuff, but actually it's explains only the basic of scene operations, and I didn't get answer to my question.

Comment: `QGraphicsView` inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea` and shows the contents of a `QGraphicsScene` in a scrollable viewport. When you set scene rect wider than window, the scrollbars would be shown automatically unless you set them off by `view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);`. It's better to provide the code to see what you have done.

Comment: I can update that I gave up totally on function "setSceneRect", and just defined the items themselves in faraway locations on the scene, and all work properly now.